# can't pass props using Link in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

[image]

```
 <Link to={{pathname:"/Watch", movie:movie}} >

using this to pass props over Watch page but can't get any value.
```

I am new to react so there might be silly mistake or might be insufficient information. please let me know regarding any extra info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `react-router-dom` v5 then route state is a property on the `to` object of the `Link`.

[RRDv5 Link](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object)

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/Watch", state: { movie } }}>...</Link>
```

If using `react-router-dom` v6 then `state` is a top-level prop.

[RRDv6 Link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link)

```
<Link to="/Watch" state={{ movie }}>...</Link>
```